# Cut polygon results do not equal to the source data

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a polygon that I would like to cut as two parts. After using the cut polygon tools, it has divided into two parts. However the total area of that two parts does not equal to the original polygon.

Example: Total area of two parts is 239.535215 m^2, Area of original polygon is 239.535226 m^2

How can I get the cut polygon result which is exactly equal to the original polygon?

Comment: I tried to set the XY Tolerance as 0.000001, but it doesn't success too.

Comment: The difference is in the 7th significant digit, that's close enough to the same for me in most cases, what coordinate system is your original and cut polygon in? I suspect that you have geographical coordinates somewhere in there and the subtle difference is a projection issue.

Comment: XY Tolerance is for vertex comparison. This appears to be a XY Resolution issue -- the coordinate values are snapped to the nearest millimeter. Unfortunately, you cannot casually change the resolution (the dataset must be recreated).  We're also discussing 7 square millimeters, which is the area smaller than the head of four pins, in the context of an object the size of a tennis court -- How accurate are your coordinate values that this is really worth any consideration?

Comment: Possibly also a float value issue, not all values are possible to be stored float.  However, in that case, your original area could be the value that was rounded to the next storable number. Or possibly all 3 numbers were altered slightly to fit the float structure.